# awk shell script help

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, awk

i have the output of  cat /proc/loadavg and 
/proc/meminfo MemFree:       1191220 kB

i need a to know who will i get a script to get then added in a logfile every 5 mins.

eg: CPU;     Mem;

```
10.0;   1191220
```

and so on so the next entry will be below that

eg: CPU;     Mem

```
10.0;      1191220
5.0;        2229882
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a spoonfeeding website. You need to at least make a good faith effort at writing your own code first, then maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Sorry Tom i am really new to this..

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to write a shell script which execute `loadavg` and `meminfo` and add there output into your desired log file. Now you can get this script repeatedly executed by `cron` by setting up a cron task. To setup cron task you will need to add entry into `/etc/crontab`. For details you can consult man entries for cron and crontab.

Also I think this questions is more suited to serverfault.com